# Difference between pointer to pointer and 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, dereference

**EDIT**
This is not a question on array decay from `char [1]` and `char *`. I know what array decay is for 1D arrays. It however seems different for `char [1][1]` and `char **` since they are not even compatible types.

I know that I can go from one of the types `char [1]` and `char *` to the other. However, it seems not as easy with `char [1][1]` and `char **`.

In my `main` function I have:

```
int main(void) {
    char a[1][1];
    a[0][0] = 'q';
    printf("a: %p\n", a);
    printf("*a: %p\n", *a);
    printf("**a: %p\n", **a);
}
```

I'm of course compiling with warnings and I know that gcc complains about the 6th line as `**a` is actually of type `char` and not a pointer type. However running the code shows that `a` and `*a` are actually the same pointer but `**a` is as expected something else (`0x71` which I assume is related to `'q'` in some way).

I'm trying to make sense of this and it seems that because `*a` and `a` are equal `**a` must also be equal to a because `**a = *(*a) = *(a) = *a = a`. It seems that the only error in this reasoning can be the types of `a`, `*a`, `**a`.

How is `a` actually stored in memory? If `a` is a pointer to another memory location (in my case `0x7fff9841f250`) then surely `*a` should be the value at that memory address which in my case is also `0x7fff9841f250`. So then `**a` would be the value at `0x7fff9841f250` which is the same value as 'a'... It seems that I cannot view the 2D array `char a[1][1]` as pointers in a way that makes sense. But then how can I think of this type? What is the type and what does `a`, `*a`, `**a`, `a[0]`, `a[0][0]` actually mean?

I have already seen [Incompatible pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539844/incompatible-pointer-type) but it does not explain what the operations `*a`, `**a`, `a[0]`, `a[0][0]` are actually doing.

Comment: Side notes : Are you new at C++? If so try to learn to work with std::vector/std::array first. In current C++ Double pointers and array pointer decay are rarely used since they cause too much opportunity for out-of-bound and dereferencing pointer bugs. If you are learning "C" then at least remove the "C++" tag.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Actually I'm working exclusively with C. However the question still applies to c++ since g++ gives exactly the same warnings and outputs as gcc. Should I still remove the c++ tag?

Comment: @spinorsaurus yes please, C++ answers can be completely different. C++ is a seperate language (with backward "C" compatibility). So while this "C" code would compile in C++ it will not be the recommended way of working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` defined as `char a[1][1]` is an array of 1 array of 1 `char`: it consists of a single byte of memory set aside by the compiler with automatic storage upon entering the scope of the function `main`, ie: a single byte of the stack area with an address that happened to be `0x7fff9841f250` when you ran the program, but could be different for a different run or another day, with another compiler, on a different architecture or host...

This piece of memory uses that same space a single `char` defined as `char a;` or as an array of 1 `char` defined as `char a[1];` or as a 3D array defined as `char a[1][1][1];` but the type is very different and the type determines how and when the memory is actually read as opposed to its address being taken.

The address of `a` is also the address of the first row `a[0]` and the address of the first element of the first row `a[0][0]`.

`a` is the name of the 2D array, when you pass `a` to a function, it *decays* to a pointer to its first element, `&a[0]`, which by definition is the address of the array but has type `char (*)[1], pointer to arrays of 1 char`. Similarly `a[0]` is an array, so passing `a[0]` to a function actually passes the address of its first element `&a[0][0]`, which is the same address but with a different type `char *`.

The syntax `*a` is evaluated the same way as `a[0]` or `*(a + 0)`, (and also more surprisingly `*(0 + a)`, and `0[a]`).  If `a` was a pointer, its value would be read when you pass `a` to `printf`, but `a` is an array so `a` decays as `&a[0]` and the address is passed without reading the memory. Similarly `*a` becomes `*&a[0]` or `&a[0][0]`, ie: `*a` passed as an argument to `printf` is just the address of the single element `a[0][0]`.  The compiler generates code that computes the address, such as *value of the stack pointer register plus 8*.

Note these remarks:

- `printf("a: %p\n", a);` should be written `printf("a: %p\n", (void *)a);` because `a` decays as a pointer of type `char (*)[1]` which might not be passed the same way nor have the same representation as `void *`, the type expected by `printf` for `%p`.
- `printf("a: %p\n", *a);` should be written `printf("a: %p\n", (void *)*a);` because `*a` decays as a pointer of type `char *` which is probably passed the same way and has the same representation as `void *`, but still is a different type from the type expected by `printf` for `%p`.
- `printf("a: %p\n", **a);` has undefined behavior because `**a` is a `char` value, which is passed as an `int` after promotion, but is definitely not the type expected by `printf` for `%p`.  The behavior is undefined.  The output is unpredictable and anything else can happen. `0x71` happens to be the ASCII code for `'q'` expressed in hexadecimal, but this behavior is not guaranteed. Some other output could be produced on a different system, with different compiler settings, at some other time, and anything else could happen.  Writing `printf("a: %p\n", (void *)**a);` would prevent the undefined behavior, but conversion from `int` to `void *` is implementation defined, so the behavior is still not guaranteed.

To summarize: *An array **has** an address and some contents, whereas a pointer has a value that **is** an address*.

Trivial comparison:

- a building is an array of apartments
- both the building and each apartment have an address
- an business card is a pointer: it can be a pointer to a building or a pointer to a single apartment, but it can also be blank (null pointer) or have an obsolete address (stale or dangling pointer) or show a phoney address (invalid pointer).
- 2D version: a street is an array of buildings...

Comment: Thank you. I think what confused me the most is that a and a[0] are both the same. In my head this would imply that a[0][0] is also the same (by recursion). But if I understand correctly the type then influences how the memory is read which makes a[0][0] different from a and a[0]. If I however cast like "char **b = (char **)a;" Then it would work as I expect and b and b[0] would be distinct. However accessing b[0][0] now becomes undefined behavior and is not actually what I want.

Do I really have to explicitly cast to (void *)? I thought the standard said that these are implicit.

Comment: `a`, `a[0]` and `a[0][0]` all have the same address.  In this particular case, they also have the same size: 1 single byte.  `char **b = (char **)a;` is meaningless:  `(char **)` is the type of the address of a pointer to `char`, yet there is no pointer in memory where `a` lives, there is not even enough space for a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a two-dimensional array

```
char a[1][1];
```

Elements of the array `a` has the type `char[1]`.

In the expression like that `*a` the array designator `a` is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `char ( * )[1]` to its first element. Dereferencing the pointer expression you get the first (and according to the declaration single) element of the type `char[1]`. Now dereferencing the expression the second time like `**a` the expression of the type `char[1]` again is converted to a pointer of the type `char *` to its first element. Thus the expression `**a` yields the first character of the first (single) "row" of the array that has the type `char` and the value `'q'` according to the assignment

```
a[0][0] = 'q';
```

According to the C Standard the expression `a[0][0]` is evaluated like `*( *( a + 0 ) + 0 )` that is the same as `**a`

The C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting):

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So this statement

```
a[0][0] = 'q';
```

may be rewritten like

```
**a = 'q';
```

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("a: %p\n", a);
```

that is better to rewrite like

```
printf("a: %p\n", ( void * )a);
```

the expression `a` having the type `char[1][1]` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element (having the type `char[1]`) of the type `char ( * )[1]` and yelds the starting address of the extent of the memory occupied by the array.

In ths call of `printf`

```
printf("*a: %p\n", *a);
```

that again should be rewritten like

```
printf("*a: %p\n", ( void * )*a);
```

the expression `*a` having the array type `char[1]` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *` and yelds the same address because elements `a[0]` and `a[0][0]` are at the same address.

This call of `printf`

```
printf("**a: %p\n", **a);
```

is incorrect because a character (the type of the expression `**a`) is outputted as an address.

Comment: *character (the type of the expression **a) is outputted as an address* more precisely: a value of type `char`, the type of `**a`, is promoted to `int` and passed as an argument where `printf` expects a `void *` for format `%p`.  The behavior is undefined.  The output is unpredictable and anything else can happen. `0x71` happens to be the ASCII code for `'q'` expressed in hexadecimal, but this behavior is not guaranteed. Some other output could be produced on a different system, with different compiler settings, at some other time, or anything else could happen.

Answer (score 0):

- `char*` is a pointer to char, it points to a single byte
- `char**` is a
  pointer to a pointer to char, it points to a 32 or 64 bits pointer
- `char[][5]` is an array type that turns to a pointer to `char[5]`, it
  points to an array of 5 bytes

Always remember that a pointer is typed (pointer to...), so that pointer+1 is incremented by the number of bytes pointed to.